# Making async javascript task in a loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

```
function(obj){
for (property in obj) {
 if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
    // some code here
   if(condition){
    obj.children = example.getdata(base, obj.name);
     }
  // some more code releated to obj
   }
 }
if (obj.length == 10)
 {
  //some more function
 }
}
```

Now i want to make **example.getdata** async but i dont want to execute **if** statement that is after **for loop** until all the sync tasks are done. 
Its more of like i want all the **example.getdata** function calls to execute in parallel and after they finish work i execute if (obj.length).

I tried using promises and push all the promises and resolve them but i dont know how to handle the return value for each function call.

Comment: Can you show your setup with promises? This is a pretty common problem, easily solved with promises.

Comment: What does exactly `example.getdata` do? AJAX request?

Comment: Yes getdata is doing a rest call but it is also doing alot of other stuff so making the whole function async is my goal

Comment: @Mathletics it was along the lines of 
var promiseslist
  promiseslist.push(example.getdata(base, obj.name));
and then at bottom
  Promise.all(promiseslist).then(function () {});
but i dont know how obj.children  will get its value for each call

Comment: Can you please show your complete code? Is `example.getData` supposed to be executed only once (or is the condition true on multiple iterations)? Why are you always overwriting `obj.children`?

Comment: condition is true multiple times and oh lets just say its obj[properties].children.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Promise* s.

Think of something like:

```
var jobs = get_jobs(data);
when_all(jobs).done(function (jobs_result) {
    console.log(jobs_result);
});
```

Where `get_jobs` returns a list or `Promise`s and `when_all` will resolve when all it's input jobs are resolved.

Comment: how will it work in a loop, can you show me a example in some more detail

Comment: Look for examples using promises, this is a pretty common use case.

Answer (score 0):

To run async tasks serially in a loop, you can't use a regular `for` loop because the `for` loop won't wait for your async operation to complete before executing the next cycle of the loop.  Rather, you have to do your own custom iteration a slightly different way.  Here's one way:

Assuming your `getdata()` function is actually asynchronous and has a completion function, you could structure things like this:

```
function myFunc(obj, callback) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    var cntr = 0;
    var results = [];
    function next() {
        if (cntr < keys.length) {
            example.getdata(obj[keys[cntr++]], function(result) {
                // do something with the result of each async operation here
                // and put it in the results array

                // kick off the next iteration
                next();
            });
        } else {
            // call the final callback because we are done now with all async operations
            callback(results);            
        }
    }
    // start the first iteration
    next();
}
```

---

If your getData function returns a promise or can be made to return a promise, then you can use promises for this too:

```
function myFunc(obj) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    keys.reduce(function(p, item) {
        return p.then(function(result) {
            // do something with the result of each async operation here
            // and put it in the results array

            return example.getdata(obj[item]);

        });
    }, Promise.resolve());
}

myFunc.then(function(results) {
    // all async operations done here, use the results argument
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clean example of a for loop using promises. If you can pick a promise library libraries like Bluebird will make it even simpler:

```
function(obj){

  var props = Object.keys(obj), p = Promise.resolve();
  props.forEach(function(prop){
    p = p.then(function(){
      if(condition){ // can access obj[prop] and obj here
        obj.children = example.getData(...); // getData returns a promise
        return obj.children; // return the promise.
      }
    });
});

Promise.resolve(obj.children).then(function(children){
    // here the async call to get `.children` is done.
    // can wait for `p` too (the loop) if we care about it
    if(obj.length === 10) // do stuff
});
```